# socket.io listen to ping events on the server

Tags: socket.io

I'm using socket.io v.1.4.5.

Is there no easy way to listen to the pings a socket.io server receives from connected sockets. I'm talking about the automatic, shockingly undocumented pings/heartbeats socket.io sends and receives (the interval of which, you can change with pingInterval). On the client, I can listen to the ping backs from the server with socket.on('pong') but not on the server.

Do I really need to create my own ping and pong events and run them on top of the ones socket.io automatically sends to have event handlers on both the server and client side?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve since socket.io already uses the pings/pongs to determine the health of the connection and automatically attempt reconnection?  Perhaps we could help better with the actual problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 In my case I'm trying to emit a warning to another socket as soon as a socket ping is not detected (and this socket therefore is "trying" to reconnect). So far I have the same doubt.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.